# CORS and server related problem on azure virtual machine

Tags: azure, nginx, ssl, mixed-content

I have a nextjs app hosted on vercel and a file upload server running 0n a docker container on azure virtual machine behind ngnix.

But when I try to call the api from frontend it gives Mixed Content Error and tells me to use https://121.112.20.7/api instead of http://121.112.20.7/api. It doesn’t happen when my frontend is on local machine. It only happens on the vercel’s one. I tried to fix this using self-signed ssl in nginx server and also allowed azure network rules to give permission Port 443. It works on only those browser where I access my api url manually and ignore security cautions.

I enabled cors in my express file upload api server and also set the response headers -

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*”
```

If anyone can help how can I access my api server from frontend

I enabled cors in my express file upload api server and also set the response headers -

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*”
```

I tried to fix this using self-signed ssl in nginx server and also allowed azure network rules to give permission Port 443.

Comment: Is there no domain name you could use instead of `121.112.20.7`? And if so, can you obtain a TLS certificate for that domain name?

Comment: No, I can't obtain a domain. Is there any other way?

Comment: Well, no. You cannot obtain a TLS certificate for an IP address, and you cannot instruct browsers to ignore mixed-content issues. One very far-fetched way would be to proxy the traffic to that IP address through another server with which you can communicate over HTTPS as opposed to HTTP.

Comment: I have a domain for frontend. So can I use it's subdomain as my server's domain and obtain TLS certificate? Can I get TLS certificate for free?

Comment: Yes to both questions.